# Find x, if $ \log _{15}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{\:}=\log _3\left(x\right)=\log _5\left(1-x\right) $

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

So how can I find the value of x, if:

$$ \log _{15}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{\:}=\log _3\left(x\right)=\log _5\left(1-x\right) $$

I tried switching everything to base 15, but that didn't work out well.

Comment: $$log_ba=\frac{\log_kb}{\log_ka}$$

Comment: should all be switched to base 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the following system disjointedly not modifying the side with $x_1, x_2$
$$
\begin{cases}
\log_{15}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right) &= \log_3 (x_1) \\
\log_{15}\left(\frac{2}{9}\right) &= \log_5 (1- x_2)
\end{cases}
$$

then check when solutions $x_1, x_2$ are same.

Comment: But how can I solve those equations ?

Comment: In the first change $\log_{15}$ in $\log_{3}$, in the second change $\log_{15}$ in $\log_{5}$ and then exponentiate sides of each equation.

Comment: so then I'll get 3^(x1)=5^x2.. and check when x1=x2?

Comment: The system of equations will give you $x_1$ and $x_2$, you'll have to check if $x_1=x_2$ because it's your initial condition: $\log_3(x) = \log_5(1-x)  \Leftrightarrow \log_3(x_1) = \log_5(1-x_2) \wedge x_1=x_2$

Answer (score 0):

If $\log _{b}({y}) =x$, Then $\log _{cb}({y}{c}^{x}) =x $.

In the case where $\log _{15}(\frac{2}{9}) =\large\log_{3}({x})$

We have $\log _{15}(\frac{2}{9}) =\large\log_{3}[\,(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{5})^{log_{15}(\frac{2}{9})}] = \log_3 (x) $.

Therefore $\large x=  [\,(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{5})^{log_{15}(\frac{2}{9})}]$ $\approx 0.5432531069176$

In the case where $\log _{15}(\frac{2}{9}) =\large\log_{5}({1-x})$

We have $\log _{15}(\frac{2}{9}) =\large\log_{5}[\,(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{3})^{log_{15}(\frac{2}{9})}] = \log_5 (1-x) $.

So $\large  [\,(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{3})^{log_{15}(\frac{2}{9})}]= (1-x)$

Therefore $\large x= 1- [\,(\frac{2}{9})(\frac{1}{3})^{log_{15}(\frac{2}{9})}]$ $\approx 0.5909416450776$

In the case where $\log_{3}(x) = \log_{5}(1-x),\,   x\approx0.5658150883239$

There is no case where the three equations are simultaneously equal